# Trying to build a Twitter News Bot

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I am trying to build a basic twitter news bot, and am wondering why this code wont run:

```
import tweepy
import feedparser

# Set up Twitter API keys and access tokens
consumer_key = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
consumer_secret = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"

# Authenticate with Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Define function to post tweets
def post_tweet(title, url):
    tweet = f"{title}\n{url}"
    api.update_status(tweet)

# Get Bitcoin-related news from Coindesk RSS feed
rss_url = "https://www.coindesk.com/feed"
feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)

# Filter news articles related to Bitcoin
bitcoin_articles = [entry for entry in feed.entries if "bitcoin" in entry.title.lower()]

# Post the selected articles to Twitter
for article in bitcoin_articles:
    post_tweet(article.title, article.link)
```

I have already added the correct keys and tokens. No errors in the terminal, just nothing happening.

I've tried re-installing the dependencies and re-affirming that the keys and tokens are right, and still nothing.